# CakePHP - MySQL - Select query and fetch result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I literally just started with CakePHP and am reading through the documentation. I am attempting to run a simple `SELECT * FROM qci_departments` query but for the heck of it cant manage to get this to work in CakePHP... Any advice would be welcome.

SamplePageController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controlle\AppController;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;


class SamplePageController extends AppController {

    /* Function for the displaying the content of the sample page */
    public function index() {
        $this->set('PageTitle','Sample Page');

        $db = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $result = $db->execute('SELECT * FROM qci_departments')->fetchAll('assoc');
    }
}
```

sample_page.ctp

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <?php

      foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '
          <tr>
            <td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Department'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Positions'].'</td>
      </tr>';
      }
    ?>

  </tdbody>
</table>
```

I understand that there is the CakePHP syntax which prevents all sort of things such as code injection, and that there is also the regular PHP syntax which seems to require the additional amount of safety and security precautions. My question is:

1. Why is the above query / fetch not working?
2. Which syntax should I follow? CakePHP or regular PHP?

Thank you,
A2k

EDIT:
To clarify, the error I receive is:

- Undefined variable: result [APP/Template/Pages/sample_page.ctp, line
  105] Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
  [APP/Template/Pages/sample_page.ctp, line 105]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set variable from controller then only you can use that in view:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('PageTitle','Sample Page');

    $db = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $result = $db->execute('SELECT * FROM qci_departments')->fetchAll('assoc');
    $this->set(['result'=>$result]); // set variable for view
    // or $this->set(compact('result'));
}
```

And you need to have SamplePage folder within View. Make index.ctp file there and copy all code from sample_page.ctp to View/SamplePage/index.ctp.

If you are using CakePhp then go with the framework's convention which will make things simple. You can go through [CakePhp blog tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html).

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt work. The `Undefined variable: result` error persists, it seems that the `$result` variable never makes it to the view, no matter how I set it. The DB connection is working and is called `default`, really no idea what the problem might be.

Comment: Oh I see.You are still missing basic conventions, see the updated answer.

Comment: Also doesnt work. CakePHP throws an error telling me to create the .ctp file in `/src/Template/Pages/sample_page.ctp`... So far, all other sites are also located in that folder.

Comment: may I know which url are you hitting ? and looks like you are using CakePhp3 right ?

Comment: I am running on the latest build (3.4.xx) and I trying to get this to work on www.domain.com/pages/SamplePage

Comment: looks like you are calling SamplePage function of PagesController ..Do you have SamplePage function within PagesController ? or are you managing that all from routing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150700/discussion-between-manohar-khadka-and-armitage2k).